# Generating plan sets using different layer configurations

Tags: qgis

I am working on a flood modelling project that will generate a very large number of plan sets.  Each set will have several plans - say a general arrangement plan and say 5-10+ sheets tracking along a intercourse. Each set of plans will be generally the same, except with a different "results" layer turned on. For example Set 1 covers the 100year flood extent, Set 2 covers the 50year flood extent, etc.

As the model develops, options tested, refinements made, etc, there is the need to reprint the drawings with the updated results layers shown.

Can I do the following with QGIS?:

1. Set up a template composer titlebox
2. Define a set of plans along a river reached for example
3. Set up a layer configuration then save the layer configuration for later reuse.
4. Print out the set of plans.
5. Change the layer configuration Then save for later reuse. Repeat this for all results.
6. At a later date, update the results files, and regenerate all the drawings using the saved layouts.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve many of the Print Composer setups by using Vincent Picavet's excellent [Atlas plugin](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/atlas). It offers support for 'coverage geometry,' which will allow you to define the areas of interest.

From the plugin's help (overview section):

> The Atlas plugin helps you create map books, or series of maps, in an automatid way.
>   The concept is to use a coverage layer, wich contains geometries and fields. This layer will define the maps to output. You can create image files or PDF files. All the composition is done in the QGIS map composer, and a specific composition is used as a template.
>   The plugin allows to replace text labels set up in the composer, with coverage layer's attribute values, enabling you to set a title, comment, document name, page number, or any dynamic information you want to display on your final maps.

[image]

You could use Python to save the layer configuration's shown/hidden state in a file, then later reload and [toggle which layers are on or off](http://plugins.qgis.org/snippets/7/). A simple [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/index.html) interface in a [PyQGIS plugin](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/index.html) would allow you to peruse the available layer configurations and choose one to load. This would require you to not significantly change the layer names, or count, to be viable over time. Shuffling the layers stacking order may also be possible through Python.

If you do not know Python or PyQt, and are looking for a developer to help with your project, you may want to post to the [QGIS Developer mailing list](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/mailing-lists.html), or find plugin developers listed at the [new QGIS plugin website](http://plugins.qgis.org/).